# Tab key is splitting the screen horizontally in tmux even when there is no key binding for tab key

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I have the below configuration in my ~/.tmux.conf

```
  1 unbind -a
  2 
  3 set -g prefix C-a
  4 unbind C-b
  5 bind C-a send-prefix
  6 
  7 set-option -g status-left-length 100
  8 setw -g mouse on
  9 
 10 # 0 is too far from ` ;)
 11 set -g base-index 1
 12 setw -g pane-base-index 1
 13 
 14 # Automatically set window title
 15 set-window-option -g automatic-rename on
 16 set-option -g set-titles on
 17 
 18 # Use Ctrl key to manage windows
 19 bind-key -n C-n new-window
 20 
 21 # Use Alt-arrow keys without prefix key to switch panes
 22 bind -n S-Left select-pane -L
 23 bind -n S-Right select-pane -R
 24 bind -n S-Up select-pane -U
 25 bind -n S-Down select-pane -D
 26 
 27 bind -n C-i split-window -h 
 28 bind -n C-h split-window -v
 29 
 30 # Use Ctrl-arrow to switch windows
 31 bind -n C-Left  previous-window
 32 bind -n C-Right next-window
 33 
 34 set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
 35 
 36 set-option -g history-limit 10000
 37 
 38 # Reload tmux config
 39 #bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf
 40
```

I have actually mapped `Ctrl+i` to split the screen horizontally. However, along with `Ctrl+i`, even the `Tab` key is splitting the screen horizontally - this has become a pain, since `Tab` will be used for auto-completion.

However, if comment out the lines -

```
 27 bind -n C-i split-window -h
```

then we don't see the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> sends the tab character `TAB`, ASCII 9 (decimal).
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> sends the line feed `LF`, ASCII 10 (decimal).
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> sends the carriage return `CR`, ASCII 13 (decimal).
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> sends the backspace `BS`, ASCII 8 (decimal).

Note I is the 9th letter in the English alphabet, J is the 10th, M is the 13th and H is the 8th. This is by design. G is the 7th letter, so expect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to send `BEL`, ASCII 7.

Your [<kbd>Tab</kbd> sends the same `TAB` character as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> does](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/563469/108618).
Your [<kbd>Enter</kbd> most likely sends the same `CR` character as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> does](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/213851/108618).
Your <kbd>Backspace</kbd>… may send `DEL`, not `BS`.

Anyway, the point is **`tmux` cannot tell apart <kbd>Tab</kbd> from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> because it gets the same input.**

*Maybe* you could reconfigure your terminal emulator to send another character (or character sequence) when you hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> (xor when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>); and adjust the config of all the relevant tools. Even if, IMO it's not worth it. Don't fight the standard, just pick another combination.

Comment: Thank you. So I think I've a problem with vertical splitting also then. Pressing backspace might be vertically splitting the screen. I'll check this. So I got to assign a new key combination for both